# How clean data in <p:overlayPanel ... when is opening or cloasing

Tags: primefaces

```
 <p:overlayPanel appendToBody="true" 
id="panel_l#{level.name.hashCode()}
    f{filterTypeConfiguration.filterType.name.hashCode()}" 
for="conrolForm_l#{level.name.hashCode()}f
    #{filterTypeConfiguration.filterType.name.hashCode()}:
    button_l#{level.name.hashCode()}f
    #{filterTypeConfiguration.filterType.name.hashCode()}" 

dynamic="true" >
```

...
and in overlayPanel I have:

```
    <p:inputText value="#{filterTypeConfiguration.textToSearch}">
      <p:ajax  id="ajaxFilterSearch" event="keyup" update="overlayForm_l
        #{level.name.hashCode()} f#{filterTypeConfiguration.filterType.name.hashCode()}
:select_l#{level.name.hashCode()}
f#{filterTypeConfiguration.filterType.name.hashCode()}"
</p:inputText>
```

I need clean data in inputText when overlayPanel is opening or closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use `p:overlayPanel` yet but I am able to trigger `p:dialog` diaglodReturn event like, I think it should be similar like this

```
 <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="@form" listener="#{backing.refreshPage}" />
```

Or

Example from primefaces showcase, How about add action attribute for button?

```
<p:commandButton id="imageBtn" value="Basic" type="button" action="#{backing.refresh}" />
    <p:overlayPanel id="imagePanel" for="imageBtn" hideEffect="fade">
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/nature/nature1.jpg" width="300" />
    </p:overlayPanel>
```